# Non-serializing in-memory database

Tags: java, hsqldb

I have the following problem:

There is a `Set<C> s` of objects of class `C`. `C` is defined as follows:

```
class C {
  A a;
  B b;
  ...
}
```

Given `A e`, `B f`, ..., I want to find from `s` all objects `o` such that `o.a = e`, `o.b = f`, ....

Simplest solution: stream over `s`, filter, collect, return. But that takes a long time.

Half-assed solution: create a `Map<A, Set<C>> indexA`, which splits the set by `a`'s value. Stream over `indexA.get(e)`, filter for the other conditions, collect, return.

More-assed solution: create index maps for *all* fields, select for all criteria from the maps, stream over the *shortest* list, filter for other criteria, collect, return.

You see where this is going: we're accidentally building a **database**. The thing is that I don't want to *serialize* my objects. Sure I could grab H2 or HSQLDB and stick my objects in there, but I don't want to *persist* them. I basically just want indices on my regular old on-the-heap Java objects.

Surely there must be something out there that I can reuse.

Comment: Voted to close since *"there must be something out there that I can reuse"* is a [**question asking us to recommend or find a** book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource, and are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Are you asking because you don't want write the code to maintain the "index" maps?

Comment: I would like to avoid writing that code. Without generics, the code would be boring and awkward to maintain. With generics (not knowing `C` ahead of time), the code would be interesting, but time consuming to write. A.k.a. a library.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found a couple of projects which tackle this problem including [CQEngine](https://github.com/npgall/cqengine), which seems like the most complete and mature library for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB provides the option of storing Java objects directly in an in-memory database without serializing them.

The property `sql.live_object=true` is used as a property on the connection URL to a `mem:` database, for example `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test;sql.live_object=true`. A table is created with a column of type OTHER to store the object. Extra columns in this table duplicate any fields in the object that need indexing.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE OBJECTLIST (ID INTEGER IDENTITY, OBJ OTHER, TS_FIELD TIMESTAMP, INT_FIELD INTEGER)
CREATE INDEX IDX1 ON OBJECTLIST(TS_FIELD)
CREATE INDEX IDX2 ON OBJECTLIST(INT_FIELD)
```

The object is stored in the OBJ column, and the timestamp and integer values for the fields that are indexed are stored the the extra columns. SQL queries such as `SELECT * FROM OBJECTLIST WHERE INT_FILED = 1234` return the rows containing the relevant objects.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_sql_conformance